# Ошибка: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'

Tags: java, android, key

Скажите,возможно ли изменить пароль не ключа,а хранилища?

> Failed to read key ptehski from store "C:\key\pavel.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.

Ибо при вводе пароля хранилища выдается такое сообщение.
Пароль не изменялся и вводиться правильно

Comment: нашел такой вариант,но как пользоваться..нет инструкции
https://gist.github.com/zach-klippenstein/4631307

Comment: пароль хранилища изменить нельзя. Если такое говорит, значит пароль действительно неправильный

Comment: @ metalurgus
т.е можно просто забыть про пароль т.к не восстановить?

Comment: Да, так же, как и можно потерять файл хранилища, и никак его не восстановить.

Comment: Не понимаю смысла ставить на хранилище пароль, сложнее чем `111`.